# Access Ruby hash variables

Tags: ruby, hash, sinatra

I am pretty new to ruby and sinatra but basically I have this route:

```
put '/user_list/:user_id' do
    puts request.params["model"]
end
```

and it returns the following

```
{"password":"36494092d7d5682666ac04f62d624141","username":"nicholas","user_id":106,"firstname":"Nicholas","email":"nicholas@macpractice.com","is_admin":0,"lastname":"Rose","privileges":""}
```

I am now having a hard time accessing values of each of those. It doesn't really seem to be in hash format so I can't really do

```
request.params["model"][:password]
```

It just returns nil..

I just need to know what I can do to access those variables, or how to configure my request parameters to be in a good format to access variables.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try `request.params["model"]["password"]`

A `Hash`'s keys can consist of both symbols and strings. However, a string key is different than a symbol key.

Note the following:

```
h = {:name => 'Charles', "name" => 'Something else'}
h[:name] #=> 'Charles'
h["name"] #=> 'Something else'
```

**EDIT:**

In your particular situation, it appears `request.params["model"]` returns a string instead of a hash. There is a method [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) which is a means of getting a substring.

```
s = "Winter is coming"
s["Winter"] #=> "Winter"
s["Summer"] #=> nil
```

This would explain your comments.

There are a couple things you can do to remedy your specific situation. I have found the most simplest way to be using `JSON`. (I'm sure there are others and maybe those will surface through other answers or through comments.)

```
require 'json'
hash_of_params = JSON.load(request.params["model"]).to_hash
hash_of_params["password"] #=> "36494092d7d5682666ac04f62d624141"
```

Comment: That just returns "password" and not the value of password.

Comment: @BlaineKasten that might be because you're sending `password="password"` in your view.

Comment: ` password != "password" ` ever. So it's actually printing the key of "password" with the above code. I've noticed that my response above is in `"foo":"bar"` format, not `"foo" => "bar"`

Comment: @BlaineKasten `{"foo": "bar"}` and `{"foo" => "bar"}` are just two different ways to  represent a `Hash`

Comment: Also notice that `{"foo" : "bar"}` is valid JSON. However, even if your params weren't a hash (like JSON), it would still respond to `{"foo" => "bar"}.to_json["foo"] #=> "bar"` like a hash.

Comment: @BlaineKasten It does appear that your `request.params["model"]` could be returning a string rather than a hash. I've edited my answer with a possible solution if this is the case.

Comment: That nailed it. Thanks a lot Charles! I thought it would have to do with JSON, so thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The standard Hash treats strings and symbols differently, and I'd be willing to bet that's what's happening in this case.

Use `request.params["model"]["password"]` to get the password.

The exception to that is when working with a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) which is part of ActiveSupport. For hashes of that type, either strings or symbols can be used to access the same elements.

Comment: I did not know about HashWithIndeferentAccess. Very nice. However, I think my return is a string. So these options aren't working for it. Any idea how to handle it knowing it's a string object?

Comment: Oh, so you mean `puts request.params["model"].class #=> String`?

Comment: @BlaineKasten *duck typing* is good for this, e.g. `request.params["model"].respond_to? :method_you_want_to_use_next` e.g. `if request.params["model"].respond_to? :fetch` then it's a hash. Have a look at [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html) and either pick out something that makes it a string, or better, something you want to call on that string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,it will work too:

```
request.params["model"][:password.to_s]
```

Comment: This just returns "password" again. I think an issue may be that my value returned from request.params["model"] is of type string..

Comment: @BlaineKasten so you mentioned `nil`, that was quite obvious as your Hash has keys which are String object. Thus `Symbol` objects like `:password` returned `nil`. To make it work I said to use `to_s` on symbol or directly use `"password"`.

Comment: I just tried it again and all it returns is `password` Thanks for the assistance though.